# why set ( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -ldl") does not work?

Tags: c, c++11, cmake, gun

when my application need link pthread library,i write `set ( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -lpthread")` in CmakeLists.txt and it works.but,when i need link dl lib, `set ( CMAKE_C_FLAGS_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -ldl")`does not work.if i use gcc directly,`gcc sqlite3.c shell.c -lpthread -ldl` works perfectly.after google,i get that  `target_link_libraries(MY_TARGET LIB1 LIB2 ... LIBN ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})` works.i tried.i did work.i want to know why `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS...)` does not work?

Comment: Is `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_C_FLAGS` (instead of just `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`) intentional?

Comment: sorry,it is a clerical error.i have corrected it.

Comment: For maximum portability you should use `set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD 1)` followed by `find_package(Threads REQUIRED)` and later call `target_link_libraries(MY_TARGET LIB1 LIB2 ... LIBN Threads::Threads)` This adds the necessary switches to the compiler and the thread library including its dependencies to the linker.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to link against the dl library. However, `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` only affect compiling, not linking. Maybe you rather want to set `CMAKE_*_LINKER_FLAGS` (the linker flags are separated for `EXE`, `SHARED` and `MODULE`).

However the *modern* way to declare the used libraries is the `target_link_libraries` command, as you've mentioned.

Here are the respective links to the documentation.

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html#variables-that-control-the-build

Comment: thank you.so,`set ( CMAKE_C_FLAGS_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -ldl")` is different from ` gcc sourcefile.c -ldl`, assume that my compiler is gcc.Is it?